# My form 'addmedico' doesn't work. How to fix button submit

Tags: angular, spring-boot, crud

I'm doing a crud in angular using as spring server and in my medico creation the submit button doesn't work as it should.

This is for my project using Spring-boot as a server, mysql for data base and in frontend Angular6. Is just a simple CRUD.

this is my medicoformcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MedicoServiceService } from '../medico-service.service';
import { Medico } from '../Medico';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-medico-form',
  templateUrl: './medico-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./medico-form.component.css']
})
export class MedicoFormComponent {

  medico:Medico;

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router,
    private medicoService:MedicoServiceService) {
      this.medico = new Medico();
     }

  onSubmit() {
    this.medicoService.save(this.medico).subscribe(result => this.goToMedicoList());
  }

  goToMedicoList(){
    this.router.navigate(['/medicos']);
  }

}
```

and this is my html for de component.

```
<div class="card my-5">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #medicoForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="medico.nombre" 
          class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre"
          required #nombre="ngModel">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="medico.apellido" 
          class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese apellido">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="especialidad">Especialidad</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="medico.especialidad" 
          class="form-control" id="especialidad" name="especialidad" placeholder="Ingrese especialidad">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ciudad">Ciudad</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="medico.ciudad" 
          class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ingrese ciudad">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect that the submit button sends the information to the server and returns the list of doctors with the method goToMedicoList(). But nothing happens.

Comment: medico: Medico = {
    nombre: null,
    apellido: null,
    especialidad: null,
    ciudad: null,
  };

Comment: doesn't work. @Francesco Fortin

Comment: onSubmit() has been called? do .subscribe got a result?

Comment: no, onSubmit() don't response and doesn't send any results. @Francesco Fortin

Comment: did you try (submit) event instead of (ngSubmit) in form ?